# Почему не работает регулярное выражение на поиск цифр в строке?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача по Java: вводится ФИО из трех слов на кириллице, надо их вывести на отдельных строках. Решить надо с помощью регулярных выражений. В строке не должно быть ничего кроме букв кириллицы, дефисов и двух пробелов.
Я пробовал

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
boolean matches = false;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^ а-яА-ЯёЁ\\-]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    matches = true;
}
```

и пробовал

```
boolean matches = input.matches("[^ а-яА-ЯёЁ\\-]+");
```

И при вводе "111 222 333" - matches=false. **Что надо написать, чтобы оно работало?**
На regex101.com данное выражение работает, разница только в экранировании символов - `[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\s\-]`

Comment: Вы говорите, что должно быть два пробела, но у вас в ВР нет такого условия. Вам, скорее всего, нужно избавиться от отрицающего символьного класса и использовать ВР для валидации специальной *последовательности* шаблонов, наподобие `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*)\\s+([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*)\\s+([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*)"); Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); if (matcher.matches()) { System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+","+matcher.group(2)+","+matcher.group(3)); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "111 222 333";
        List<String> stream = Stream.of(input.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тк это обучение, то пока пользоваться Stream нельзя. Надо решить задачу простым использованием регулярного выражения. Я просто не могу понять почему не работает выражение в посте.

Answer (score 0):

Символ `^` в начале блока `[]` в регулярном выражении создает отрицание. Т.е. вы сделали в точности да наоборот, правильное выражение `"[ а-яА-ЯёЁ\\-]+"`.

Советую сайт, на котором легко проверять регулярные выражения без длительной компиляции https://regex101.com/

Помимо этого, вы тестируете строку `111 222 333`. Чтобы сделать поддержку цифр в том числе, нужно еще добавить `0-9` диапазон в блок `[]`, в таком случае регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так `"[ а-яА-Я0-9ёЁ\\-]+"`.

Comment: Я поправил задание. Мне как раз нужно проверить строку на наличие чего-то кроме перечисленного в РВ. И про сайт я тоже писал в посте.

Comment: @БорисСамойлов я проверил ваш код из вопроса. в случае, когда `input` равен `111 222 333`, в этом случае `matcher.find()` возвращает `true`, как и ожидается.

Comment: Там видимо, лишнее что-то было в коде. Задача решена. Очень помогла статья с англ части портала (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)